# Downloading excel file from Box.com by using python 3.6.3

Tags: python

I have read many posts, but I'm still struglling some problem.
I'm trying to download excel file file from Box.com to cet os folder by using python script. Here, I'm using Box API to download file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import two classes from the boxsdk module - Client and OAuth2
from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2

# Define client ID, client secret, and developer token.
CLIENT_ID = None
CLIENT_SECRET = None
ACCESS_TOKEN = None

# Read app info from text file
with open('app.cfg', 'r') as app_cfg:
    CLIENT_ID = app_cfg.readline()
    CLIENT_SECRET = app_cfg.readline()
    ACCESS_TOKEN = app_cfg.readline().replace('\n', '')

#################################################


from boxsdk.network.default_network import DefaultNetwork
from pprint import pformat



class LoggingNetwork(DefaultNetwork):
    def request(self, method, url, access_token, **kwargs):
        """Base class override. Pretty-prints outgoing requests and incoming responses. """
        print('\x1b[36m{} {} {}\x1b[0m'.format(method, url, pformat(kwargs)))
        response = super(LoggingNetwork, self).request(
            method, url, access_token, **kwargs
        )
        if response.ok:
            print('\x1b[32m{}\x1b[0m'.format(response.content))
        else:
            print('\x1b[31m{}\n{}\n{}\x1b[0m'.format(
                response.status_code,
                response.headers,
                pformat(response.content),
            ))
        return response


###########################################

##########

# Create OAuth2 object. It's already authenticated, thanks to the developer token.
oauth2 = OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Create the authenticated client
client = Client(oauth2, LoggingNetwork())

#######################################################

items = client.folder(folder_id='0').get_items(limit=100, offset=0)
for item in items:
    with open('FileFromBox.xls', 'wb') as open_file:
        client.file(item.id).download_to(open_file)
        open_file.close()
```

I think I am successfully authenticated and got file_id.
After excuting this script, files are created in home directory, but those files contain no data. I tried to do cat command, but no data show up. I'm sure files are placed in box.com. Could please someone tell me what is the wrong in this code?

Comment: you dont need to close the file since the with statement handles that for you.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have deleted close part, but it still does not work. It seems like that I'm not getting content of excel file in right way.

Comment: can you link me to the file? it might be a problem with that.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Could you tell me what does it mean 'can you link me to the file?'. Sorry for lacking of my knowledge.

Comment: cna you give me the excel file? just upload it anywhere so I could run tests with it.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Please find the following link.https://app.box.com/s/31m94zs7kg76dd0y0tx30iz3gjs73fp8